# Не загружаются стили Laravel

Tags: css, laravel

Есть проблема с загрузкой статических 2 из 5 файлов стилей (не загружаются вообще). Происходит это при первом запуске (при обновлении вроде загружаются и потом кешируются), но у новых пользователей и через режим "Инкогнито" статические файлы не грузятся (не все, а именно 2).

- Сервер Nginx отдает ответ 200 "".
- в заголовках ответа еще есть "Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT".
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Mozilla выдает mime-type. Думал проблема в размере файла, но 1 файл весит 76 кбайт - полагаю, это не может привести к такой ошибке.

Еще из причин - ответ сервера 'text/html' вместо 'text/css'.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]